# i want to load data from mysql to jsp but I have an unprocessable error

Tags: java, mysql, apache, jsp

```
enter code here
```

1. this is java code to load data from database to jsp

   package dao;

   ```
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;

   import model.Category;
   import utils.DBConnect;

   public class CategoryDAO {

       public ArrayList<Category> getListCategory() throws SQLException {
           Connection connect = DBConnect.getConnection();
           ArrayList<Category> listCategory = new ArrayList<>();
           String sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
           PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareCall(sql);
           ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

           while (rs.next()) {
               Category category = new Category();
               category.setCategoryID(rs.getInt("CategoryID"));
               category.setCategoryName(rs.getString("CategoryName"));
               listCategory.add(category);
           }

           return listCategory;
       };

   }
   ```
2. this is html file to display data, i am load category

   ```
   <ul class="drop">
                                <%
                                   for (Category c : cateDao.getListCategory()) {
                                %>
                                   <li><a href="product.jsp?category=<%=c.getCategoryID()%>"><%= c.getCategoryName() %></a></li>
                                <% 
                                   } 
                                %>
                               </ul>
   ```

The error section will be posted in the comment

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about my answer, but...
Method connect.prepareCall calls stored procedures from database, so, may be you should use connect.prepareStatement instead.

Comment: i try but not successful!

Comment: lỗi thông báo ở đoạn code này PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement(sql);